# malloc(): memory corruption in a weird place

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, corruption

I've been dealing with an annoying memory corruption error for a couple of hours. I've checked every related thread here, and I couldn't fix it.

First of all, I'm writing a simple Terminal in C. I'm parsing the commands between pipe (|) and redirection (>, <, etc.) symbols and place them in the queue. Nothing complicated!

Here's the data structure for the queue;

```
struct command_node {
    int index;
    char *next_symbol;
    struct command_node *nextCommand;
    int count;
    char **args;
};
```

When I'm storing small strings in the **args pointer, everything works just fine. However, when one of the arguments is long, I get malloc(): memory corruption error. For example, the following 1st command works fine, the 2nd command causes the error

```
   1st:  ls -laF some_folder | wc -l

   2nd:  ls -laF /home/enesanbar/Application | wc -l
```

I run the debugger, it showed that the malloc() call for the new node in the queue causes the error.

```
newPtr = malloc( sizeof(CommandNode) );
```

I'm carefully allocating the array of strings and freeing after I'm done with them as follows:

```
    char **temp = NULL;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * number_of_args);

    /* loop through the argument array */
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_args; i++) {
        /* ignore the remaining commands after ampersand */
        if (strcmp(args[i], "&") == 0) return;

        /* split commands by the redirection or pipe symbol */
        if (!isSymbol(args[i])) {
            temp[count] = malloc(sizeof(strlen(args[i])) + 1);
            strcpy(temp[count], args[i]);
            count++;

            /* if it is the last argument, assign NULL to the symbol in the data structure */
            if (i + 1 == number_of_args) {
                insertIntoCommands(&headCommand, &tailCommand, temp, NULL, count);
                for (j = 0; j < count; j++) free(temp[j]);
                count = 0;  // reset the counter
            }

        }
        else {
            insertIntoCommands(&headCommand, &tailCommand, temp, args[i], count);
            for (j = 0; j < count; j++) free(temp[j]);
            count = 0;  // reset the counter
        }
    }
```

I must have missed something, or there's something I don't know about the **args fields and the allocation of the new node although it's nothing I haven't done before.

Comment: `temp[count]` <-- what is `count`?

Comment: it's to keep track of where to put the next argument and i'm also storing it for convenience when printing stuff for debugging.

Comment: `sizeof(strlen(...` is probably not what you want. drop the sizeof

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue, but how could wrapping a number around the sizeof cause an error in the allocation of a node? I'm just trying to understand out of curiosity.

Comment: You try to get the size of the pointer inside the  `strlen` function and not the lenght which is provided through the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but how could wrapping a number around the sizeof cause an error in the allocation of a node? I'm just trying to understand out of curiosity.

Like I was saying in my comment, you try to get the size of the pointer inside the strlen function and not the lenght which is provided through the function.

Please take a look at the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(void){
    char *name = "Michi";
    size_t length1, length2;

    length1 = strlen(name);
    length2 =  sizeof strlen(name);

    printf("Length1 = %zu\n",length1);
    printf("Length2 = %zu\n",length2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Length1 = 5
Length2 = 8
```

---

One more thing, after you `free(temp[j])` don't forget to `free(temp)` also.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void){
    long unsigned int size = 2,i;
    char **array;

    array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * size * size);

    if (array == NULL){
        printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
         array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);
    }

    /* do code here */

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
         free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```